# Onclick function appears for less than a second,then disappears

Tags: javascript, onclick

Want to see the onclick function event.but not working.in line 15 when showComment function called by onclick nothings working.

```
const loadCatagori = async () => {
  const url = `https://openapi.programming-hero.com/api/news/categories`
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const data = await res.json();
  displaycatagori(data.data.news_category);
}
loadCatagori();
const displaycatagori = datas => {
  const catagory = document.getElementById('catagory');
  catagory.innerHTML = ``;
  for (let it = 0; it < datas.length;it++)
  {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = `
    <div onclick="showComment(${datas[it].category_id})">
      <a href="" class="hover:underline underline-offset-[10px]">${datas[it].category_name}</a>
    </div>
      `;
    
    catagory.appendChild(div);
  };
}

const showComment = inputId => {
  const count = document.getElementById('count');
  count.innerText = inputId;
}
```

Here's the HTML Code.I want to Show my result into "count" id by showComment() function from javascript.the result shows only few moments.then it disappears.

```
   <section class="container sm:mx-auto py-5 bg-[#FFFFFF] rounded-lg">
          <h1 class="px-4 text-xl "><span id="count"></span> items found for catagory <span id="cata_name"></span></h1>
        </section>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that is what you are asking but is it because you are reloading with `href=""`? Does changing your `a` element to `<a href="" onclick="event.preventDefault()" class="hover:underline underline-offset-[10px]">` help?

Comment: thanks. I got the ans.. I remove the href ,now it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <a href=""
> ```

Clicking a link with a relative URL to the same page will cause the browser to navigate to that URL (resetting the DOM to the state representing in the raw HTML) as soon as the JavaScript has finished running.

Use a `<button type="button"...` to create an element that the user can click on to trigger a JavaScript effect. Don't use a link (unless the link provides [default behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) that you override if JS is available and you [prevent the default behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) of that link when the JS runs).